# Are there repercussions to changing the IP address of a mailserver?

Tags: email

I want to migrate my mail server from a data centre in the states to a data centre in Europe. Is there any danger that by doing so, email coming from my server may be marked as spam, due to IP address changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly yes, but it's more likely to be caused by going with a known-spammy provider than changing countries. Do what you should already be doing today - publish SPF records and don't send spam.

Also, do some research on your provider - see if they often end up on RBLs.

Comment: Good idea, I'll do that. I'll update my SPF record, try to get a reverse DNS record, and add a DKIM, and I guess cross my fingers. (and also not send spam).  I should be ok. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

1. Just because the IP changes, the server won't be marked as spam necessarily.
2. If you have SPF records for your domain saying your current IP is allowed to send email from your domain, then you will need to update those DNS records for the new address, as failing SPF checks will make your mail look like spam.
3. If you have forward DNS (mailserver.example.org -> current.ip) and reverse DNS (current.ip -> mailserver.example.org) then you will need to update that, as mismatched DNS ( the hostname resolves to your old IP that it's not using, and the reverse of the new IP doesn't resolve to the right hostname) will make your email look more spammy.